# Opening an External PDF in Emacs from Terminal

Tags: latex, osx

I am using Emacs on the Mavericks OSX Terminal. I can open the TeX file fine, but I can compile a pdf via `C-c C-c`. Is there some way that I can open the pdf in an external window via the command line? I tried running `C-c C-c` and then `C-c C-c` again, but it said that was undefined. I have also looked here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11613/launching-an-external-pdf-viewer-from-emacs-auctex-on-a-mac-osx-fails

But that didn't work either. I would really like to be able to run LaTeX in Emacs from the command line, but I do a lot of live TeXing and I need to continuously check the pdf. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: AUCTeX is not the default in Emacs, so make sure you really are using it (if you want to).

Comment: As @pst said, AUCTeX is not the default, so your keybindings may be different. If you haven't added anything to your `.emacs` config file, you probably are using the default `LaTeX-mode` (or `latex-mode`: I forget which is the default).

Comment: It should not matter whether you use Emacs in a terminal or as a stand-alone GUI -- if you call an external program to display the pdf, that external program doesn't care which version of Emacs called it.  I'm not sure how my previous comment got deleted, but it was to the following link that contains various methods for generating and displaying a pdf from Emacs with and without AUCTeX and it works for OSX and Windows:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  I have been using the non-AUCTeX solution for about 3 years for personal and business use.